# How to add a new number to every element in a specific column, using linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk, sed

I have a huge text file like this:

```
Chr1  11000   11500   geneA  0
Chr1  11500   12000   geneA  6
Chr1  12000   12500   geneA  0
Chr1  12500   13000   geneA  7
...
Chr30  120000   125000   geneZ  7
Chr30  125000   130000   geneZ  7
```

I need to indiviually number every instance of the gene name (column 4.)  So for example, it would become the following:

```
Chr1  11000   11500   geneA_1  0
Chr1  11500   12000   geneA_2  6
Chr1  12000   12500   geneA_3  0
Chr1  12500   13000   geneA_4  7
...
Chr30  12500   13000   geneZ_939  7
Chr30  12500   13000   geneZ_940  7
```

Anybody have any idea of how to do this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: @jww - Which I presume is why my answer got downvoted as well? (and fair enough if that's the case)

Comment: jww always downvotes all answers when he leaves that comment then I and others upvote them all to compensate.

Comment: @EdMorton stackoverflow is weird :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea just looking at column 4 is you use the column data as an index into an `associative array`/`hash` of counters:

```
awk '{i[$4]++; print $4 "_" i[$4]}' gene
```

And to keep the other data around...:

```
awk '{i[$4]++; c4 = $4 "_" i[$4]; gsub($4, c4);print;}' #and optionally >outFile
```

If you're dead set on overwriting the file in place, I don't think standard awk supports that:

```
perl -i~ -ape 'if (!($F[3] =~ /_\d+$/)) { $i{$F[3]}++; $c4 = "$F[3]_$i{$F[3]}"; s/$F[3]/\Q$c4/}' gene
```

This processes `gene` and creates a `gene~` backup file.  The perl one also won't process the same file twice (if it sees `_` and a number at the end of column 4, it skips the row)

Caveat: If your gene name exists in rows 1-3, your output will be broken.  Looks unlikely based on your sample data though.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there anyway I can print this into the current text file?  That way, the new column is already in there?

Comment: @Steveman30290 - I wouldn't recommend overwriting your current file in place with awk.  Normal is a redirect, then mv the new file over the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the below command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {i=1;} {print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4"_"i" "$5; i++;}' filename > tmpfile
mv tmpfile filename
```

use tabs instead of spaces according to your file or need.